# iPad AV Foundation video Capture

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, video

I'm new to video on IOS devices and I have a question. Can I use AV Foundation to record video to a file, and display the stream concurrently on the iPad screen in a Modal Formsheet view? Or does the video feed have to be full screen?

Any links, tutorials or resources you can provide to get started would help a lot.